# My dictionary is empty after try loop

Tags: python, try-except

I am trying to run the below code to read the csv file and make it so that I can search by month to get the respective months utilities charges. If I put a print statement above "try" it will print every line. however, when I try to print (or reference) the bills defaultdict it should create it is empty. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help on this!!

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

source = 'C:/Users/George/PycharmProjects/Day6-Monthly-bills/Monthly Bills record - Sheet3 (1).csv'
Bills = namedtuple('Utilities', 'Month Gas Electric Water Total')


def lookup_bills_by_month(data=source):

    bills = defaultdict(list)
    with open(data, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in csv.DictReader(f):
            try:
                month = line['Month']
                electric = int(line['Electric'])
                gas = int(line['Gas'])
                water = int(line['Water'])
                total = int(line['Total'])
            except ValueError:
                continue

            b = Bills(Gas=gas, Electric=electric, Water=water, Total=total}
            bills[month].append(b)
            print(bills)

    return bills


bills = lookup_bills_by_month()

print(bills)
```

Comment: Your "except ValueError: continue" clause is probably hiding the reason.  If it gets executed for every line, then your bills dict will never be populated.  Print something in the except clause so you can see what is going on.

Comment: I guess the values are not integers but flooding point and that's why you always get empty dict.

Comment: Both of these things were super helpful! Thank you! Those were not integers, they were indeed floats. Really, thank you for the help!